Where is the "opinion-based" part of my question?
I asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78479004/which-branch-to-checkout-when-working-on-prs-for-a-forked-repo) and it was promptly closed as "opinion-based".
Where is the opinion-based part? Is this where I added some "I think"? (which were intended to show that I do not know if my approach is correct).

My question: where should I place this branch? say there are multiple, equally valid, answers to that - how does one provide an answer not based on opinion?

@Clive by saying "at develop because this is where your code diverge". Or "here nad here because the merge will be straightforward". I am not asking for a color but fro a technical place where to branch off.

Why is there a meta for SO if you get -3 just by asking where opinion based parts are? A few yers ago I decided to not come back here for mental wellness reasons - now I know why.

The question stands, though. If it can’t have an answer that isn’t based on one’s own preference, it’s opinion-based. That’s how I read it anyway

Also you’d be better off approaching this in isolation, and not stacking any legacy angst onto it. I promise, that will be better for any mental wellness.

@Clive there must be a good way to branch off a branch for a PR. Worst is that I won't know what that place is (I am absolutely sure that branching the PR from a randomplace is not at all a good idea. Which means that there is a better idea, which is to branch from XXX because YYY" :)

@Clive as for the angst you are right. It is just that I have not seen a lot of sites like SO where you are constantly on a rollercoaster. One day your questions are great and you get great answers, and the day after BAM! -15 because something :)

there are best practices for git workflows. strictly speaking, there might be some "opinion" leeway to this, but judging by value, there will be one or a few ways to move forward that are clearly correct and valuable, with any room for "opinion" being not worth the headache, but a great chance to discuss such design decisions.

I think there's an objective question about how remotes and tracking branches correspond to GitHub forks in there, but I'm not currently awake enough to do a good job summarizing it (also, I am used to a very different workflow than GitHub uses, so I'm not exactly certain how they would end up in specific situations.)

Why don't you simply ask the author / maintainer of the repository you are forking? They would be the best person to answer your question, I don't think this is suitable for Stack Overflow.

One of the best way to identify a opinion based question is asking: Is there any answer that can be wrong? With your question, there are no wrong answers.

@Braiam: starting the branch from a random commit would be a good answer? Even for someone like me who is a true beginner in git/github/PR this doe snot sound right.

And yet it is objectively viable answer. You would still accomplish the stated "objective".

How to use branches in git is essentially the opinion. I have worked for three companies that used git and all three did it different. Not only that, but teams within the same company did it different. Branches tend to hook into release and deployment automation flows, that's where best practices go out the window.

@Gimby my question was where to branch off for a PR, because I expected there is a right place to do that. Which was ultimately confirmed in one of the comments - but I deleted the question because apparently it is worth -10 or so and I have my answer. The fact that others won't profit from it seems to be a minor point - and this is th eessence of SO for me.


Where is the opinion-based part?

In the actual, core substance of it:

[I...] fail to understand exactly what the workflow for forked projects should be.
...
Where should I place this branch?
...
Which commit should I checkout to work on the right place? The "right place" is, I think, the place where the simplemonitor development is today, so that I can start from the freshest possible place.

The point is: you are expecting someone else to determine the criteria for "should". In general, if you are asking people to choose between alternatives on Stack Overflow, it's your responsibility to tell them the rules for making the choice in their answer.
Put another way - from your comment here:

by saying "at develop because this is where your code diverge". Or "here nad here because the merge will be straightforward"

It's not the answerer's responsibility to come up with a "because" unless it's specifically answering an explicit "why".

Tyler reworded the last part, to commit you to your idea:

Which commit do I checkout to work on the place where the simplemonitor development is today, so that I can start from the freshest possible place?

But I think this is still not as good as it could be. Honestly I think the question is still lacking in focus (and it appears someone else agreed), as it also states:

I do not understand why I have a develop branch and an origin/develop one and why they are not just one.

My advice is to turn that part into a question explicitly, and ask just that, first. Once you understand why there are separate branches, the decision to make may become obvious. Otherwise, go back to the drawing board and ask separately. It seems like you have both a "how does this work?" type question and also a "how do I solve this problem?" type question; but clearly, solving problems depends on an understanding of the system in which the problem will be solved - so getting an answer to the first question, whether by forming it separately or by doing your own research, is a prerequisite to asking the second.
Both of these also seem to me like questions that might be answered more than adequately by existing Q&A. But I don't really follow Git questions here, so I can't be sure.
